# Styling PHP Output with a CSS file

Tags: php, html, css

How do I attach a style sheet to PHP output? Besides bold and italic, it would be nice to give my output some style.

```
        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array ($query))
{
echo '<b>'.'School Name: '.'</b>'.$row['School_Name'].'<br />';
echo '<b>'.'CoSer Code: '.'</b>'.$row['COSER_Code'].'<br />';
echo '<b>'.'Product: '.'</b>'.$row['Product_Name'].'<br />';
echo '<b>'.'Cost Description: '.'</b>'.$row['Cost_Description'].'<br />';
echo '<br />';
}
```

Comment: The style sheet should be linked from the `<head>` section (which does not appear in the code you've provided) of the HTML document.

Comment: Put your data in whatever element you'd like (div, table, td, span) and then just apply a style to that element.

Comment: give the elements in your PHP output `id`s and `class`es which you then style in your CSSfile.css (Edit: of course you have to link your stylesheet as mentioned in the first comment)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I am not going to downvote your question but please do not write php like that. First take a breath and cool down. Learn about tpl files or master layouts or template engines or views or a framework that will provide you some solutions. Please. Using html at the top of your php will cause (was causing) header problems later on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `<style> style code here </style>` or

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<?php 
  //your code here
?>
```

At the top of the PHP page to use CSS.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer is the correct one, please mark it as accepted so others can view the correct answer quickly :D

Answer (score 0):

Use this for your output:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/CSSfile.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php //Put Here your code

 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Give your output `id`s and `class`es which you can than style in your css.

For example you could give your `<b>` tags another text font with this css code:

```
b { font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif; }
```

For more information about changing fonts look here http://de.selfhtml.org/css/formate/zentrale.htm